# How to convert QDateTime to GMT Unix Stamp

Tags: c++, qt, date, gmt

I am trying to convert `QDateTime` to Unix Time Stamp:

```
QDateTime PubDate = audioFile->GetPublishingdate();

uint UTC_Time = PubDate.toTime_t();
```

For today's date `Mon 22 Sep 00:00:00 2014` I am getting `1411358400`.

If I use [this website](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to check if timestamp is correct then I obtain `1411344000` for today's date. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QDateTime` treats any value you store into it as a local date-time by default. You need to use method `setTimeSpec` to make `QDateTime` know that it keeps GTM.

```
QDateTime PubDate = audioFile->GetPublishingdate();

PubDate.setTimeSpec(Qt::UTC);

uint UTC_Time = PubDate.toTime_t();
```

Comment: Typo on line 2: PutDate instead of PubDate